# how to search for a value stored in variable from a file using awk/ grep

Tags: awk, grep, tcl

It might be trivial, but I am facing problem in using awk for simple purpose like printing row in a file using tcl script.
I have variable var :

```
set var manager
```

sourcefile.txt:

```
ajay manager account 45000
sunil clerk account 25000
varun manager sales 50000
amit manager account 47000
tarun peon sales 15000
deepak clerk sales 23000
sunil peon sales 13000
satvik director purchase 80000
```

I want to put command inside tcl script (awk/grep) which use variable **var** to search for string in source file and then print the 4th column of the line containing the string.
I don't want to search for manager directly, but using **var** .
I used:

```
awk -v pat="$var"  {$2 ~ pat {print $4 }} sorcefile.txt
```

But it is giving me error saying

```
awk: 'pat' argument to '-v' not in var=value form
```

Also inside tcl script:

```
awk '/manager/ {print $4}' sourcefile.txt
```

gives error, and

```
awk {/manager/ {print $4}} sourcefile.txt
```

works well
So, the required output:

```
45000
50000
47000
```

The command I need to put it inside a file, and then execute the file.

Comment: Which error ? What kind of syntax is that `awk ... { $2 ~ pat {print $4 }}` ? Please use shellcheck.net to fix the obvious issues.

Comment: Sir, this is not working; showing can't read file pat

Comment: it is showing badly placed ()'s

Answer (score 2):

It's the position of the quotes.

```
$ tclsh
% set var manager
manager
+% exec awk -v pat="$var" {$2 ~ pat {print $4}} sourcefile.txt
```

No output. Let's ask the shell to `echo` the awk command instead of executing it:

```
% exec echo awk -v pat="$var" {$2 == pat {print $4}} sourcefile.txt
awk -v pat="manager" $2 == pat {print $4} sourcefile.txt
```

Note how the double quotes are part of the pattern there?

Let's move the double quotes a bit:

```
% exec echo awk -v "pat=$var" {$2 == pat {print $4}} sourcefile.txt
awk -v pat=manager $2 == pat {print $4} sourcefile.txt
```

Note how the quotes are gone? Let's execute it now:

```
% exec awk -v "pat=$var" {$2 == pat {print $4}} sourcefile.txt
45000
50000
47000
```

This relates to the [Tcl rule for double quotes](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M8) -- the opening quote must be the **first character of a word**.

In the first case, the awk `pat` variable is literally `"manager"`, and as none of the $2 values contains quotes, no matches occur.

Comment: but where would that "argument to '-v' not in var=value form" error come from? They'd need to end up running `awk -v pat blahblah...` to get that. Or would TCL eat the equal sign too in some case?

Comment: I don't entirely trust the question contained all the details.

Answer (score 1):

this could be simply done in tcl

```
set var ...
set fi [ open "file.txt" ]
set lines [split [read $fi] "\n"]
close $fi
foreach line $lines {
        set la [ split $line ]
        if { [ lindex $la 1 ] eq $var  } {
                puts [ lindex $la 3 ]
        }

}
```

note that list index start at 0 and awk's `$4`' is tcl `[lindex $la 3]`

Comment: I used your suggestion but i dont know why it is showing unpredicted error: -> set : Variable name should start with a letter. I don't know why it is showing such error

Comment: did you replace `...` with actual value ?

Comment: That error message sounds like your not running this in a tcl shell. Variable names can be pretty much anything in Tcl, including the empty string. So it would never tell you that the name should start with a letter.